# Using Regex with SQL Server BIDS

Tags: sql-server, regex, report, bids

I'm writing a report using SQL Server BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio, VS2008), and I have the requirement to remove punctuation from field values.

For example, if the field value is "Hello, World!", I want the report to show the value as "Hello World".  I'm aware in this example it'd be easy enough to use the Replace function, nested:

```
=Replace(Replace(Fields!Description.Value,",",""),"!","")
```

But this quickly becomes 'ugly' if I have to remove more than just "," and "!" characters.  So, in short:

**Can I use Regular Expressions to format field values in a SQL Server BIDS report**?

If the answer is "no", that's fine, it'll save me wasting time trying to find it!  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Usage of Regex in expression formula (though this one is for phone numbers):

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!Phone.Value, "(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{3})[ -.]*(\d{4})", "($1) $2-$3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process large set of rows on client side may take some time. So i propose to move Regex logic on Server side.

You can use CLR function for this.

Look for examples here: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

**Update**

If you want to process on client side, let you look at using expressions (include regex) in reports:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Though this sounds like a good suggestion, in this instance I don't have sufficient access to the server to change the data provided.

I'm using a FetchXML statement to retrieve the data, any processing has to happen in the report (client-side).